# Modify routing in Gatsby site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, gatsby

I want to set up pagination in a Gatsby blog. In my `pages/index.js` page I am storing the posts, the "chunked" posts (e.g. chunks of 4 posts per page), and the current page number:

```
this.state = {
  allPosts: props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges,
  postChunks: [],
  currentpage: 0,
};
```

Currently, if I go to `localhost:8000` it points to this component, loads the first 4 posts and displays them. I want to be able to go to `localhost:8000/page2` and for this route to point to the *same* component. Currently it takes me to the `404` page. How can I modify the routing so that all `pageX` routes go to the same `index.js` component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Gatsby, you create routes programmatically.

Check out gatsby-paginate which makes it easy to create paginated index pages https://github.com/pixelstew/gatsby-paginate/

Answer (score -1):

If you use react-router you can just use `<Route path="/" component={Blog} />`

Any path that follows from the root "/" will go to the same Blog component (you can avoid this by declaring 'exact path' instead). I'm guessing you can use the url to determine which chunk you display then.

Comment: Yeah I'm wondering how to do this specifically in Gatsby's architecture, best practices etc.